# Break the line of a JFreeChart in Java

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart

In MATLAB i can plot:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,NaN,5,6];
y=[1,2,3,4,NaN,5,6];

plot(x,y);
```

and it plots 2 lines that aren't joined (see image below):
[image: one series but 2 lines]

Is there a similar digit to NaN that I can use with JFreeChart that I can use to separate the data like above? Or do I have to add a different series for every time I want a line-break?

*[apologies if my terminology is incorrect, feel free to correct it if it helps other people understand!]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by the adding a null y value into the XYSeries:

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("name");
series.add(1,1);
series.add(2,2);
...
series.add(0,null); // note the x value cannot be null or you get an error
```

I hope this helps